# quiero actualizar los registros sql por numero

Tags: sql, transact-sql

```sql
DECLARE @indice int
DECLARE @in int
SET @indice = 1

WHILE @indice<=3

BEGIN
  ;with cte as
(
  select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by nombre) as rn
  from Personas
)
select *
from cte
where rn = @indice
 
  PRINT @indice
   SET @indice = @indice + 1; 
   update personas set PersonID=rn
      
END;
```

pero no toma el numero de renglon no entiende la variable rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Modifico la respuesta, porque indicas que hay repetidos):

Aunque el resultado final esperado no está claro, y parte de lo que estás haciendo no  parece muy lógico, porque se puede hacer directamente en una sola sentencia.

Voy a exponer un escenario.

```
Create table personas
             (
             id       int identity(1, 1)
           , personId int
           , nombre   char(1)
             );
```

Y los valores

```
Insert into personas (personId, nombre)
values
(null,'c'),
(null,'a'),
(null,'a'),
(null,'a'),
(null,'c'),
(null,'e'),
(null,'d'),
(null,'c'),
(null,'a'),
(null,'b');
```

[image: Res1]

O lo que es lo mismo, tenemos una tabla personas donde la columna PersonId para algunas filas no tiene el contenido que necesitamos. Como estas usando row_number entiendo que quieres un orden alfabético. La siguiente consulta, valida lo que quieres hacer.

```
with cte as
(
  select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by nombre, (select null)) as rn
    , row_number() over (partition by nombre order by nombre,(select null)) as rnNombre
  from Personas
)
Select * from cte;
```

[image: Res2]

Los valores repetidos, se muestran secuencialmente, porque en la cte, en la columna rn, hemos puesto un `order by nombre, (select null)`. O lo que es lo mismo, me ordenas por nombre y después sin un criterio definido, pero a fin de cuentas ordena.

La solución puede ser.

```
with cte as
(
  select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by nombre, (select null)) as rn
  from Personas
)
Update cte set personId = rn
```

El resultado obtenido

[image: Res]

El motor solo, sabe identificar al ser una tabla la que se menciona en la cte que corresponde la update a personas y las filas quedan ordenadas por el criterio visto anteriormente.

Comment: ;with cte as
(
  select *
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by nombre) as rn
  from Personas where nombre='alberto'
)
select * from cte
update p 
        set personId = rn
    From personas p 
        join cte on p.nombre = cte.nombre;                                                        lo intente con nombre iguales y en lugar de poner los numeros en orden secuencial a todos les pone 1 y al final pone el ultimo renglon cuando quisiera que pusiera aun siendo repetidos los numeros secuenciales es decir 1,2,3 si hay 3 albertos que estos los siga enumerando de forma secuencia

Comment: La respuesta ya esta modificada en base a tener o no repeticiones. No obstante, si la pregunta estuviera bien definidia, y hubieras expuesto un escenario con la salida esperada, las respuestas serían apropiadas a lo esperado.